# Implement Load Balancer on AWS on existed server with Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm a backend developer who is a very beginner in Server Administrative here.

I have ec2 instance sitting on AWS with Elastic IP assigned to it.
There are several domains point to this Elastic IP (from my clients).

The server then, response with appropriate content.

At this point, I would like to start using load balance as the number of traffics is  increasing.

---

### The question is

Would I be able to apply Load Balancer while still not changing IP Address (Elastic IP) that domains pointing to?

I would be a bit difficult to get to all clients and ask them to update the DNS record point to new IP Address.
So having the same IP would be an ideal solution for me.

It will be a big help if you guys could shed light for me on this.

Answer (score 3):

No. The ELB has a DNS entry that you can setup on your DNS provider or on Route 53. This DNS is the only external link to the ELB and ELBs don't have elastic IPs.  Also, keep in mind that the DNS doesn't change on your ELB but the IP can change at discretion of Amazon.

Also, Amazon uses it's own internal mechanism to access instances behind load balancer and I'm pretty sure it doesn't use external addresses (most likely internal)

Another alternative is to setup your own HAproxy instance in EC2 and configure it with an Elastic IP, but that's a little bit more work. (Also, you have to monitor it closely as you would have to manage it in case of changes in traffic patterns)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Rico. At least I know it's better to setup ELB and ask the existed to re-point their domain sooner than rather (before the number of clients is increase).

This info help me a lot, appreciate your help mate :)